overwrite server-side cookies from client-side
In my sveltekit app I have a "add to order" button in a product page. When the user clicks on it there is a cookie set with the product code, then the user is sent to the order page.
On the order page there is a form where the user can change product, on submit it will refresh the cookie updating its value.
The problem is that when I set a cookie from the order page, it won't be updated if I try to create a new order, it will be updated only if I change product in the order page or if I manually delete the cookie. I've set the same path but it looks like server side cookies have the priority.
+layout.svelte
  function handleClickOrderButton() {
    const currentProduct = $page.params.product_id;
    document.cookie = `orderSelectedProduct=; Max-Age=0; path=/; SameSite=None; Secure`;

    try {
      if(currentProduct){
        document.cookie = `orderSelectedProduct=${currentProduct}; Max-Age=604800; path=/; SameSite=None; Secure`;
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    } finally {
      goto(`/${$page.params.database_id}/new-order`);
    }
  }

Form action
export const actions = {
  changeSelectedProduct: async ({cookies, url, locals, request}) => {
    if (!locals.user) {
      return redirect(302, `/login`);
    } else {
      const userId = locals.user.id;
      const formData = await request.formData();
      const selectedProduct = formData.get("product");

      try {
        cookies.set("orderSelectedProduct", selectedProduct, {
          path: "/",
          maxAge: 604800,
          sameSite: "None",
          secure: true,
        });
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    }
  }
};


Perhaps don't use cookies at all. localStorage is the place to put these things, especially if you request stuff from the server using the order number anyway

The only thing I generally use cookies for is identifying a session/authentication. Everything else I would put into some kind of storage (session, local, IDB) or something on the server/DB keyed by user. Things relating to navigation belong in the URL.

@mplungjan but localStorage is only client-side, I need something that can be accessed from both. I tried query parameters but I want to avoid tainting the url

What I meant is if your pages use the order number all the time to request stuff from the server, then the server does not need to use the cookie to retrieve it. You just always pass it in the get or post request instead of ALL requests EVER sent to the server
